# How do I get the PAC SIDs from a SpnegoAuthenticationToken using Spring Security Kerberos 2.0?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

Using [kerb4j](https://github.com/bedrin/kerb4j) and Spring Security, I can get PAC SIDs from a SPNEGO token (allowing my app to determine which authorities are granted in Active Directory for a user):

```
@Bean
public SpnegoAuthenticationProvider spnegoAuthenticationProvider() {
    SpnegoAuthenticationProvider provider = new SpnegoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setTicketValidator(sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator());
    provider.setExtractGroupsUserDetailsService(authoritiesPopulator());
    provider.setServerSpn(servicePrincipal);
    return provider;
}

 @Bean
 public AuthoritiesPopulator authoritiesPopulator() {
    return new AuthoritiesPopulator();
 }

public class AuthoritiesPopulator implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<SpnegoAuthenticationToken> {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(SpnegoAuthenticationToken token) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        try {
            SpnegoInitToken spnegoInitToken = new SpnegoInitToken(token.getToken());

            SpnegoKerberosMechToken spnegoKerberosMechToken = spnegoInitToken.getSpnegoKerberosMechToken();

            Pac pac = spnegoKerberosMechToken.getPac(token.getKerberosKeys());

            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> roles;

            if (null == pac) {
                roles = Collections.emptyList();
            } else {
                PacLogonInfo logonInfo = pac.getLogonInfo();

                PacSid[] groupSids = logonInfo.getGroupSids();
                roles = new ArrayList<>(groupSids.length);
                for (PacSid pacSid : groupSids) {
                    if ("S-a-SID-NUNBER"
                            .equals(pacSid.toHumanReadableString())) {
                        roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")); 
                    }
                }                
            }
            
            return new User(token.username(), "N/A", roles);
```

Unfortunately, kerb4j doesn't work with Spring Boot 3.  I would like to use the official [Spring Security Kerberos library](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-kerberos) since it has been updated for Spring Boot 3.

How do I get to the PAC SIDs using Spring Security Kerberos 2.0?

**Here's what I've tried**

The `SpnegoAuthenticationProvider` is a type provided by kerb4j. I couldn't find an equivalent type in Spring Security Kerberos. The closest I found was `KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider`. I attempted to create that bean as follows:

```
public KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider() throws Exception {
    KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider provider = new KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setTicketValidator(sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator());
    provider.setUserDetailsService(authoritiesPopulator());
    return provider;
}
```

The problem is that the `setUserDetailsService` of `KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider` does not accept an argument type of `AuthenticationUserDetailsService`. It accepts a `UserDetailsService` which defines a method `loadUserDetails`. That method takes a `String` argument rather than a `SpnegoAuthenticationToken`. So, the Spring framework will call my `loadUserDetails` implementation with a username String instead of the needed `SpnegoAuthenticationToken`.

Is this a work-in-progress and will be part of 2.1? Or can this done using 2.0?